# Azure App Service S2 network bandwidth

Tags: azure, azure-networking, azure-web-apps

How can I find out the network bandwidth/throughput for an Azure App Service S2 Windows host?

Microsoft do not seem to publish this information about app services anywhere, but we have been asked to provide this for a client.

I did read somewhere that a similarly spec'ed A2 virtual machine has a throughput of 500 Mbps.  But I am not sure that this also applies to app service virtual machines.

Comment: Maybe you could check this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#app-service-limits).

Comment: The App Service Limits on that page do not specify the network throughput.  The bandwidth limit stated is just for the total amount of data leaving the data centre.  There might be relevant info elsewhere on that page, but I cannot find it.

Comment: In fact, network bandwidth depends on many factors, it seems Azure does not provide this quota.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft have told me that the App Service S2 is equivalent to a Standard A2 virtual machine which has an expected network bandwidth of 500 Mbps